# Pro T705 thermostat: heat kicks on when it drops below 64.5 despite it being set to kick on at 60

Tags: thermostat, heating

I have a [Pro T705](https://www.pro1iaq.com/t705) thermostat.

At night, I have it set to only heat when the temperature drops below 60 degrees F. I have the wake up temperature set to 73 degrees.

I have a Netamo system in the same room which tracks the actual temperature real-time. It's within 5 feet of the thermostat and at roughly the same height on the wall.

The heat is consistently coming on when the temperature drops below 64.5 degrees and it continues to heat to 73.
[image]

I've checked the temperature schedules. I've checked the times.

The only other thing I can guess is that it's because of the "swing" settings - that the difference between the lowest temp point and the heat setting is too wide.

Could it be the swing settings or is there something else going on?

UPDATE======

Experimented last night to see if the answer of it being "adaptive intelligent recovery" was correct. Adjusted the wake up time to hours later, kept the setting to only heat when the temperature drops below 60 degrees F.

Confirmed that heat didn't kick on when it dropped below 64.5 and the wake up heat setting was well in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably "adaptive intelligent recovery".  That is, the thermostat learns about the building's heat loss and capacity of the heating system.   So if you want the wake up temp at 73  by 8:00 AM, the tstat "learns" that it takes 2 hours (just an example) to get there, so it turns the heating system on at 6:00.  From your graph (impressive, BTW), it doesn't seem like it's turning the system on during the night, only in the early morning to get to temp by the time you set as "wake up" temp. What you might be seeing is the space just hadn't cooled down to 60 before it was "time to turn on the system" to get you to your 73 degree set point by when you wanted it.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it looks like the system is turning on around 4:30AM to reach 73 degrees by 6AM, based on the graph.

Comment: @TylerH  Yes, agreed.   I was just using example setpoints and times.  It wouldn't be unusual for a heating system to take and hour and a half to achieve a temp rise of 13 degrees. (or even the 9 degrees according the OP's graph).

Comment: This sounds _very_ reasonable. It would only be made better if someone could find that in the operating manual for the thermostat in question.

Comment: @FreeMan  I looked at the manual and specs and it didn't say.    But AIR is the only thing that makes sense here.